# How to print some elements of an array in a new line in Ruby?

Tags: arrays, ruby, printing

I have a Ruby script that outputs an array:

```
arr = ["filename1", integer1, integer2, "filename2", integer3, integer4, "filename3", integer5, integer6 ...]
```

What I need is this array to be more readable; I'd like to print only three elements in a single line, so:

```
"filename1", integer1, integer2,
"filename2", integer3, integer4,
"filename3", integer5, integer6,
```

I managed to get to the point of having an array of arrays with
`arr.each_slice(3).to_a`:

```
arr = [["filename1", integer1, integer2], ["filename2", integer3, integer4], ["filename3", integer5, integer6] ...]
```

but I still can't make each array of the array be printed in a separate line.

Is there a way of doing this?

The ideal output would look something like this:

```
filename1: integer1, integer2
filename2: integer3, integer4
filename3: integer5, integer6
```

but I understand that adding the colon after `filename` is another issue, I would probably have to play around with `join()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formatting an array can be done with the [%] method[1](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.0/String.html#method-i-25)

```
arr.each_slice(3){|trio| puts "%s: %d, %d" % trio}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first step is indeed `.each_slice(3)` as you figured out correctly. I'm assuming `arr` is already the sliced array.

An easy option would be to just join them together with commas.

```rb
arr.each do |elements|
   puts elements.join(', ')
end
```

If you want the characters used for joining to be different, then you cannot use join, but string interpolation is easy enough.

```rb
arr.each do |filename, integer1, integer2|
   puts "#{filename}: #{integer1}, #{integer2}"
end
```

This will print the string content. If that's what you want, you're done. If you also want to include the quotes around the string, I suggest calling `.inspect` on it before display.

```rb
arr.each do |elements|
   puts elements.map(&:inspect).join(', ')
end
```

```rb
arr.each do |filename, integer1, integer2|
   puts "#{filename.inspect}: #{integer1}, #{integer2}"
end
```